# iPad 2 shows as camera on my computer

Tags: camera, ipad

When I connect my iPad 2 to my computer, it is displayed like a camera, and I can't put any files on it.

What could be the problem?

Comment: Is iTunes installed? The only way to put files into the iPad is via iTunes.

Answer (score 0):

According to this, when it shows up as a camera, then you have to sync it.

[Yahoo answers - its suppose to show up like that](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20110620170128AAu6C8Z)

[Macworld - iPad File Transfers](http://www.macworld.com/article/159805/2011/05/ipad_file_transfers.html) (There's a paid app to use it like a thumb drive?)

From the above link:

> The sad truth is that iPad file management is a chore

[How to sync iPad 2 to computer, software download](http://www.ipad-transfer.com/guide/sync-ipad-2-to-computer.html)

Comment: @ Gokturk I added another link in case itll be useful to ya

Comment: Neither of the links has anything to do with the initial problem (namely the iPad only showing as a camera). The first link you posted was missing altogether. The software you linked to is not free, it's only free to download and nothing else.

Comment: @slhck - The links have everything to do with the problem, I am going to guess the author does not have iTunes installed, that would be the first step.

Comment: The link says its suppose to show up like that, and if it does just sync it.

Comment: @Ramhound Yes, then that's what I'd suggest doing first. I can't believe linking Yahoo Answers is the real answer here though. Same goes for the third party software, which is ridiculously overpriced and does in no way look better or more trustworthy than any of the other "iPad 2 transfer" software you get when you spend half a minute googling it.

Answer (score 0):

Start here and work through the [iPad Troubleshooting process](http://support.apple.com/kb/TS1538). In my case, I had to upgrade iTunes...

Answer (score 0):

All Ios devices have this feature, however, they simply emulate a USB file exchange protocol that similar to a USB pen drive/Mass Storage.

However, it only allows you to read/copy (and I think delete) from the device - it does not allow you to copy on to the device - you have to use iTunes.

However, some devices (Not sure the rules, I saw it on an old Ipod, but not on my Ipad or Ipod Touch) have an option you can set in Itunes that allow you to use it as a mass storage device.